# Add a value manually to the request and receiving that request with the value after response

Tags: php, http, session, post, request

I am building a session for a project. And i am so far that i get through the request the session_name as key with the session_id as value.

so now i want to restart the old session with the `id` that i already have.

**The Problem**

I wanna try to get this name of the session, passed through the `request`, which was send by `POST`. Anyone an idea, how to do this?

Already tried it with `stream_context_create()`.... somethings missing, but don´t know what.

**Code so far:**

```
public function sendPost($value) {
    $url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index.php';
    $data = array('key' => $value);

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data['key']) . "\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $data['key']
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) { echo 'POST failed!'; }
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($result);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: copied most of the code, from another question

Answer (score 0):

Create your own session class, and use the DB for storage.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Then you can renew a session, there is no guarantee php wont remove the session file, also there are security implications when doing these things.

For example I would not rely on just a session cookie, I would also record the users RemoteIP address, but I would also not rely on just the IP address.  Probably the best way is to set your own cookie like a `remember me` type option.

Comment: ok don´t wanna do that so big, that´s just an schooling project. is there no way to send the value with post over the request?